# Migrating to ARC "cannot assign to self in a class method"

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a class with a class method looking like:

```
+ (id)itemWithTitle:(NSString *)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    self = [[self alloc] initWithTitle:title target:target action:action];

    return self;
}
```

It works just fine with manual reference counting but when i try to use it with ARC I get the error: "cannot assign to self in a class method". Is there a way I could fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is really related to ARC. The difference may be that with ARC the compiler gives you a warning/error on this.

In general in class methods (those beginning with + instead of - and being called differently) self does not refer to a particular object. It refers to the class. With 
[self alloc]
you create an object of the very class regardless whether it was subclassed or not. 
If this were an instance method [[self class] alloc] would work quite equivalent. But you are in a class method for good reasons.

Why don't you just return the result in this case?

```
+ (id)itemWithTitle:(NSString *)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithTitle:title target:target action:action];
}
```

If your class name is Foo then you could go for:

```
+ (id)itemWithTitle:(NSString *)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    Foo *newMe = [[self alloc] initWithTitle:title target:target action:action];
    // Here you have access to all properties and methods of Foo unless newMe is nil.
    return newMe;
}
```

or more general without having access to the methods and properties of Foo:

```
+ (id)itemWithTitle:(NSString *)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    id newMe = [[self alloc] initWithTitle:title target:target action:action];
    return newMe;
}
```

Comment: thanks! its working now. i've downloaded this somewhere to learn more about obj-c. Weird its working without ARC and when I try to migrate it to ARC, it's pointing out this error. I'll mark it as answered as soon as the timer is gone! :)

Comment: Yes, it is working without ARC but it is not correct. What happens in your code is: 1. self refers to the class object of the class itself. Class is actually an object in Objective-C. 2. Then you get something of type id returned from alloc init. You assign that to your self pointer. Self from now on does not point to the class any more but to the instance as self would do in instance methods too. So depending on the remaining code it could work but it is a bad pattern at least.

Answer (score 2):

Your pre-ARC code should not have misused the `self` keyword. It should have looked something like this.

```
+ (id)itemWithTitle:(NSString *)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    MyClass* obj = [[[MyClass alloc] initWithTitle:title target:target action:action] autorelease];

    return obj;
}
```

In ARC, the only difference is that you could remove the `autorelease`.

Comment: it would not leak using ARC ... where you would also have to get rid of the `autorelease`

Comment: sorry, the original code had some more code like release etc, but i removed it to make it clear i want to use it in ARC :)

Comment: strange, I tried your answer as well but it was still giving me an error before. now its just working... thanks anyway!

Comment: Maybe you didn't remove the `autorelease`.

Comment: I did, somehow my xcode doesnt update everytime unless i manually remove some files.. :s